# Store Scrapy Items into MySQL via Pipeline Issue

Tags: python, mysql, database, scrapy, pipeline

I am trying to add items into MySQL database but I can't get through it, the data is not stored and I am getting this error at this time.

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),
                    1,
                    (("'fr_FR'",),),
     ' at line 34
```

Below is my settings.py file

```
BOT_NAME = 'Test1001'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['Test1001.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Test1001.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'Test1001.pipelines.dropifdescription',
                  'Test1001.pipelines.DropToDb',}
```

My items.py File

```
class Test1001Spider2Item(scrapy.Item):
    base_domain = Field()
    sitemap_url = Field()
    sitemap_link = Field()
    link_locale = Field()
    link_type = Field()
    link_title = Field()
    link_description = Field()
    link_url = Field()
    link_site_name = Field()
    link_article_tag = Field()
    link_article_section = Field()
    link_article_published_time = Field()
    link_meta_keywords = Field()
    link_publisher = Field()
    link_article_author = Field()
    link_twitter_card = Field()
    link_twitter_description = Field()
    link_twitter_title = Field()
    link_twitter_image = Field()
    link_facebook_app_id = Field()
    link_facebook_page_admins = Field()
    link_rss = Field()
    link_twitter_image_source = Field()
    link_twitter_site = Field()
    link_twitter_url = Field()
    link_twitter_creator = Field()
    link_apple_app = Field()
    link_facebook_video = Field()
    link_facebook_page_id = Field()
    link_id = Field()
    link_image = Field()
    url = Field()
    domain_id = Field()
    crawled_date = Field()
```

How my spider gets the data from websites:

```
if datematch:
            item['link_title'] = ogtitle
            item['link_description'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract()
            item['link_locale'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:locale"]/@content').extract(),
            item['link_type'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:type"]/@content').extract(),
            item['link_url'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:url"]/@content').extract(),
            item['link_site_name'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:site_name"]/@content').extract(),
            item['link_article_tag'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:tag"]/@content').extract(),
            item['link_article_section'] = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:section"]/@content').extract(),
```

And finally my pipelines.py file:

```
import MySQLdb
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from datetime import datetime

class dropifdescription(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        # to test if only "job_id" is empty,
        # change to:
        # if not(item["job_id"]):
        if not(item["link_title"]):
            raise DropItem()
        else:
            return item


class DropToDb(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="Test1001", charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO Main (
        url,
        domain_id,
        link_locale,
        link_type,
        link_title,
        link_description,
        link_url,
        link_site_name,
        link_article_tag,
        link_article_section,
        link_article_published_time,
        link_meta_keywords,
        link_publisher,
        link_article_author,
        link_twitter_card,
        link_twitter_description,
        link_twitter_title,
        link_twitter_image,
        link_facebook_app_id,
        link_facebook_page_admins,
        link_rss,
        link_twitter_image_source,
        link_twitter_site,
        link_twitter_url,
        link_twitter_creator,
        link_apple_app,
        link_facebook_video,
        link_facebook_page_id,
        crawled_date,
        link_image
        )
                        VALUES (
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        %s,
                        )""",
                                (
                                    item['url'],
                                    item['domain_id'],
                                    item['link_locale'],
                                    item['link_type'],
                                    item['link_title'],
                                    item['link_description'],
                                    item['link_url'],
                                    item['link_site_name'],
                                    item['link_article_tag'],
                                    item['link_article_section'],
                                    item['link_article_published_time'],
                                    item['link_meta_keywords'],
                                    item['link_publisher'],
                                    item['link_article_author'],
                                    item['link_twitter_card'],
                                    item['link_twitter_description'],
                                    item['link_twitter_title'],
                                    item['link_twitter_image'],
                                    item['link_facebook_app_id'],
                                    item['link_facebook_page_admins'],
                                    item['link_rss'],
                                    item['link_twitter_image_source'],
                                    item['link_twitter_site'],
                                    item['link_twitter_url'],
                                    item['link_twitter_creator'],
                                    item['link_apple_app'],
                                    item['link_facebook_video'],
                                    item['link_facebook_page_id'],
                                    item['crawled_date'],
                                    item['link_image'],
                                ))

            self.conn.commit()


        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])


            return item
```

So, why I can't store the data to Database and where am I doing it wrong..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is it failing? What error message are you getting? Stacktrace, maybe?